How to sink into imxg2dcompositor after taking video from 2 camera?
I'm trying to sink videos from 2 v4l2src into imxg2dcompositor and then sink them into a tcpserversink, the pipeline works perfectly:
gst-launch-1.0 \
  v4l2src device=/dev/video2 io-mode=dmabuf ! \
  video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1,format=YUY2 ! \
  queue2 ! c.sink_0 \
  v4l2src device=/dev/video3 io-mode=dmabuf ! \
  video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1,format=YUY2 ! \
  queue2 ! c.sink_1 \
  imxg2dcompositor name=c \
   sink_0::xpos=0 sink_0::ypos=0 sink_0::width=700 sink_0::height=500 \
   sink_1::xpos=700 sink_1::ypos=0 sink_1::width=700 sink_1::height=500 ! \
  queue2 ! v4l2h265enc extra-controls="encode,frame_level_rate_control_enable=1,h265_mb_level_rate_control=1,video_gop_size=30,video_bitrate=2048000,video_bitrate_mode=1,h265_level=11,h265_profile=4;" output-io-mode=dmabuf-import ! \
  queue2 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=12346

but when I try to embed it on my app in c code I just don't know how to write the c.sink_0 of my src video. Bellow is my help, sorry if I ask something stupid, it's my first project with gstreamer.
#include <gst/gst.h>

#define GST_V4L2_IO_DMABUF 4
#define GST_V4L2_IO_DMABUF_IMPORT 5

typedef struct _CustomData
{
    gboolean is_live;
    GstElement *pipeline, *vsrc1, *queue, *vsrc2, *queue1, *compositor, *queue2, *encoder, *queue3, *gdppay, *tcpserversink;
    GMainLoop *main_loop;

} CustomData;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CustomData data = {};
    GstBus *bus;
    gst_init(NULL, NULL);

    // factory make elemenets
    data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");
    data.vsrc1 = gst_element_factory_make("v4l2src", NULL);
    data.vsrc2 = gst_element_factory_make("v4l2src", NULL);
    data.queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue2", NULL);
    data.queue1 = gst_element_factory_make("queue2", NULL);
    data.queue2 = gst_element_factory_make("queue2", NULL);
    data.queue3 = gst_element_factory_make("queue2", NULL);
    data.compositor = gst_element_factory_make("imxg2dcompositor", NULL);
    data.encoder = gst_element_factory_make("v4l2h265enc", NULL);
    data.gdppay = gst_element_factory_make("gdppay", NULL);
    data.tcpserversink = gst_element_factory_make("tcpserversink", NULL);

    // settings up the elements from pipe
    // video 2
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.vsrc1), "device", "/dev/video2", "io-mode", GST_V4L2_IO_DMABUF_IMPORT, NULL);

    // filter1
    char *capsString;
    capsString = "video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1,format=YUY2";
    GstCaps *caps = gst_caps_from_string(capsString);
    GstElement *filter1 = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", NULL);
    g_object_set(filter1, "caps", caps, NULL);
    gst_caps_unref(caps);

    // video 3
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.vsrc2), "device", "/dev/video3", "io-mode", GST_V4L2_IO_DMABUF_IMPORT, NULL);

    // filter2
    char *capsString2;
    capsString2 = "video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1,format=YUY2";
    GstCaps *caps2 = gst_caps_from_string(capsString2);
    GstElement *filter2 = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", NULL);
    g_object_set(filter2, "caps", caps2, NULL);
    gst_caps_unref(caps2);

    // compositor
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.compositor), "name", "comp", NULL);

    // encoder
    char *encConfig = "encode,frame_level_rate_control_enable=1,h265_mb_level_rate_control=1,video_gop_size=30,video_bitrate=2048000,video_bitrate_mode=1,h265_level=11,h265_profile=4;";
    GstStructure *encSt = gst_structure_new_from_string(encConfig);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.encoder), "extra-controls", encSt, "output-io-mode", GST_V4L2_IO_DMABUF_IMPORT, NULL);
    gst_structure_free(encSt);

    // tcpserversink
    data.tcpserversink = gst_element_factory_make("tcpserversink", "sink");
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.tcpserversink), "host", "0.0.0.0", NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.tcpserversink), "port", 12346, NULL);

    // add elem to bin
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(data.pipeline), data.vsrc1, filter1, data.queue, data.vsrc2, filter2, data.queue1, data.compositor, data.queue2, data.encoder, data.queue3, data.gdppay, data.tcpserversink, NULL);

    g_print("before error\n");
    GstPad *sinkpad0 = gst_element_request_pad_simple(data.compositor, "comp.sink_0");
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(sinkpad0), "xpos", 0, "ypos", 0, "width", 700, "height", 500, NULL);
    GstPad *sinkpad1 = gst_element_request_pad_simple(data.compositor, "comp.sink_1");
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(sinkpad1), "xpos", 700, "ypos", 0, "width", 700, "height", 500, NULL);
    g_print("after error\n");

    // link elements
    if (!gst_element_link_many(data.vsrc1, filter1, data.queue, data.compositor, NULL))
        g_error("Failed to link all elements...");
    if (!gst_element_link_many(data.vsrc2, filter2, data.queue1, data.compositor, NULL))
        g_error("Failed to link all elements...");
    if (!gst_element_link_many(data.compositor, data.queue2, data.encoder, data.queue3, data.gdppay, data.tcpserversink, NULL))
        g_error("Failed to link all elements...");

    int ret = gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
    {
        g_printerr("Unable to set the data.pipeline to the playing state. \n");
        gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
        return -1;
    }
    else if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_NO_PREROLL)
    {
        data.is_live = TRUE;
    }
    else if (ret == GST_STATE_READY)
    {
        g_print("Pipeline playing...\n");
    }

    data.main_loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    g_main_loop_run(data.main_loop);

    g_main_loop_unref(data.main_loop);
    gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
    gst_object_unref(bus);

    return 0;
}

I get the output :
before error
(:980): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 19:57:10.525: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(:980): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 19:57:10.525: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
after error
Pipeline playing...
